# Black scholes, issues inferring T(time to expiry) andS (underlying price)) from wrds SPX dataset

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, historical-data

I'm working on a project with the SPX option data from wrds. This data doesn't provide the underlying price at the time of the observation, or the time to expiry at the time of the observation. However, it does have strike price, implied volatility and some greeks at the time of observation including delta and vega. Strike price is given as 1000*actual_strike_price (ie 2000000 is the 2000 strike price). Implied volatility is presented in absolute terms, ie 0.2 is 20 implied vol. Delta is presented in normal units (-1.0, to 1.0). Vega is presented as the change in option price for a 1 unit change in implied volatility in absolute terms (ie vol going from 0.2 to 1.2). Using strikedelta and vega, I am inferring the missing values as follows.

First, I compute d1 and N'(d1).

ESraw['d1'] = np.where(ESraw['cp_flag'] == 'C', norm.ppf(ESraw['delta']), norm.ppf(1 + ESraw['delta']))
ESraw['Nprime_d1'] = norm.pdf(ESraw['d1'])

Then, I define a function func that computes the difference in underlying price S that we get from computing S by using our value of d1 or by using our value of vega that are backed out the by Black Scholes equations for d1 and vega for a given "guess" t. I am ignoring dividend and interest rate factors as those don't matter for options whose underlying is a futures contract.
def func(t, row):
S_d1 = row['strike_price']*math.exp(row['d1'] * row['impl_volatility'] * (t^0.5) - 0.5*t * row['impl_volatility']^2.0)

```
S_vega = 1000.0*row['vega']/ (row['Nprime_d1'] * (t^0.5))  # Assuming Nprime_d1 is defined
return S_d1 - S_vega
```

I then use scipy.optimize.root to find the value of T (time to expiry) for which this difference is zero with the initial guess being the number of calendar days to expiry / 365.

def get_T_fresh(row):
if np.isnan(row['vega']):
return np.nan
t = row['days_to_expiry'] / 365.0

```
# Find the root of the function using scipy.optimize.root directly
curried_func = partial(func, row=row)
result = root(curried_func, t)
T = result.x[0]
return T
```

I believe that there must be some error in my computations, or an issue with certain data points given as I am geting abnormally large values of T for some data points.

Examples :
T is too large :171.4364023898521
date               2016-01-06 00:00:00
symbol              SPX 170616P2950000
exdate             2017-06-16 00:00:00
cp_flag                              P
best_bid                         975.9
best_offer                       983.3
impl_volatility                0.12876
delta                        -0.965327
gamma                         0.000046
vega                          33.46535
theta                         -14.4161
strike_price                   2950000
days_to_expiry                     527
d1                           -1.816159
Nprime_d1                     0.076677
t                                  NaN
Name: 16978, dtype: object

T is too large :33.120747400056324
date               2016-01-08 00:00:00
symbol              SPX 170616P3300000
exdate             2017-06-16 00:00:00
cp_flag                              P
best_bid                        1394.1
best_offer                      1400.5
impl_volatility               0.218258
delta                        -0.947863
gamma                         0.000103
vega                          119.5805
theta                        -18.95631
strike_price                   3300000
days_to_expiry                     525
d1                           -1.624477
Nprime_d1                     0.106629
t                                  NaN

Am I supposed to account for interest rate and dividends? Is my issue due to these points possibly being american options?